# Proving functions are in $L_1(\mu)$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> Let $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Take $f,g
>  \in L^1(\mu)$. Prove that $\sqrt{f^2+g^2}$ and $\sqrt{\vert fg\vert}$
>    are in $L^1(\mu)$.

First, I prove that $h = \max\{f,g\} \in L^1(\mu)$. Let $A = \{x \in \mathcal{X} \mid f(x) \geq g(x)\}$. Then:

$$ \begin{align} \int_{\mathcal{X}} h \ \mathrm{d}\mu &= \int_A h \ \mathrm{d}\mu + \int_{A^c} h \ \mathrm{d}\mu \\ \int_{\mathcal{X}} h \ \mathrm{d}\mu &= \int_Af \ \mathrm{d}\mu + \int_{A^c} g \ \mathrm{d}\mu \\ \int_{\mathcal{X}} h \ \mathrm{d}\mu &\leq \int_{\mathcal{X}}f \ \mathrm{d}\mu + \int_{\mathcal{X}} g \ \mathrm{d}\mu < +\infty \end{align}$$

So $h \in L^1(\mu)$ as I wanted. If I suppose that $f,g \geq 0$, I think the following will do: let's prove that $\sqrt{f^2 + g^2} \in L^1(\mu)$. We have:

$$\begin{align} \int_{\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{f^2 + g^2} \ \mathrm{d}\mu &\leq \int_{\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{2\max\{f,g\}^2} \ \mathrm{d}\mu = \sqrt{2}\int_{\mathcal{X}} \vert\max\{f,g\}\vert \ \mathrm{d}\mu < \infty\end{align}$$

since $\max\{f,g\} \in L^1(\mu) \iff |\max\{f,g\}| \in L^1(\mu)$. I'm a bit insecure about this.

And for the other one:

$$\int_{\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{\vert fg\vert} \ \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \int_{\mathcal{X}}  \sqrt{|\max\{f,g\}^2|}\ \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_{\mathcal{X}}  \max\{f,g\}\ \mathrm{d}\mu < + \infty.$$

Not secure about this one, either.

Can someone help me fixing the details? Alternate solutions are also welcome. Thank you.

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \leqslant \lvert a\rvert + \lvert b\rvert$ and $2\lvert ab\rvert \leqslant a^2 + b^2$ for real $a,b$. Throw in a couple more absolute values for the complex case.

Comment: Oh my god. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @DanielFischer now speaking seriously, thank you. I managed to do it, and registered my solution here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ashamed of myself for not realizing the problem was so elementary, I'll register my solution here, in case it helps someone. We have that for all $a,b \in \Bbb R$: $$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \leq \sqrt{|a|^2 + 2|ab| + |b|^2} = \sqrt{(|a|+|b|)^2} = ||a|+|b|| = |a|+|b|$$

and: $$(|a|-|b|)^2 \geq 0 \implies a^2 - 2|ab| + b² \geq 0 \implies |ab| \leq 2|ab| \leq a^2 + b^2 \implies \sqrt{|ab|} \leq \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.$$

Applying this to the functions, we obtain:

$$\int_{\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{f^2 + g^2} \ \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \int_{\mathcal{X}} |f| + |g| \ \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_{\mathcal{X}} |f| \ \mathrm{d}\mu + \int_{\mathcal{X}} |g| \ \mathrm{d}\mu < +\infty$$

since $f,g \in L^1(\mu) \implies |f|,|g| \in L^1(\mu)$. We conclude that $\sqrt{f^2+g^2} \in L^1(\mu)$. And now, we just use that: $$\int_{\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{|fg|} \ \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \int_{\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{f^2 + g^2} \ \mathrm{d}\mu < +\infty$$
and hence $\sqrt{|fg|} \in L¹(\mu)$.