# Struggling with something 4 sources use "clearly" with (involving $\inf$ of a set)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is technically measure theory but it as much real analysis.

We have a Measure $\mu:R\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\cup\{\infty\}$

We define the outer measure $\mu^*$ to be:

$\mu*(E)=\inf\{\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu(E_n)|E_n\in R, E\subset\cup^\infty_{n=1}E_n\}$

This means immediately, that $\forall\{E_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ with $E\subset\cup^\infty_{n=1}E_n$ we have $\mu^*(E)\le\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu(E_n)$ - I am happy with this.

It then shows that $\mu*(E)\le\mu(E)$ for $E\in R$ by noting that if $E_1=E$ and $E_n=\emptyset$ otherwise that:

$\mu^*(E)\le\mu(E)$

**Problem**

I am not happy (at all) with $\mu^*(E)\ge\mu(E)$ which I need and 4 sources say "clearly" with.

Lets take a simple case as used in my preferred book (Halmos, Measure Theory), suppose $E\in R$ and $E_n\in R$ too.

If $E\subset\cup^\infty_{n=1}E_n$ then by a previous theorem (which I am totally happy with) we have:
$\mu(E)\le\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu(E_n)$ it then says "so that $\mu^*(E)\ge\mu(E)$"

Where has this come from?!

I think I am missing some magical property of $\inf$ - I'll refrain from posting more info unless it is required.

Final word: The book is showing that $\mu^*(E)=\mu(E)$ where $E\in R$

**My work**

Urgh, too long, I've been musing/scribbling on this for 2 days. I  think I need to show:

$\mu(E)\le\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu(E_n)\le...\le\mu^*(E)$ but I cannot put the "..." in, I've tried "An ntroduction to measure and integration" by "Inder K. Rana" Introduction to measure theory by Tao, some lecture notes I've found online, another measure theory "Measure and integration" by Taylor.

I am missing something so trivial these books neglect to mention it! Surely!

Answer (score 2):

You have that $$\mu(E) \leq \sum_{n \geq 1}\mu(E_n),$$ where the $E_n$ cover $E$. Since this inequality is true for **every** collection $E_n$ covering $E$, you have that $\mu(E)$ is a lower bound for the set $$\left\{\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu(E_n)|E_n\in R, E\subset\cup^\infty_{n=1}E_n\right\},$$ so that $\mu^*(E) \geq \mu(E)$ follows from the definition of infimum.

Comment: I both love and hate you right now. I love you because - "Of course" - I hate you because you've made me feel unbelievably silly!

Comment: That's life! :)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Kah3JPO.png

Comment: Genius HAHA! The struggle is real. I think the [most silly question I have ever asked here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989581/proving-functions-are-in-l-1-mu) is, ironically, about measure theory :P

Comment: Last one: http://i.imgur.com/fx4uaxJ.png

Comment: It's a bit out of line but I know you've been doing measure theory for over a year, so incase you never see it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123907/is-this-an-outer-measure-if-so-can-someone-explain-the-motivation