# Is this an outer measure, if so can someone explain the motivation

Tags: measure-theory

I'm studying Measure Theory, and following Halmos's book and measures came first.

I like measures, I also picked up a book on Probability, that motivated measures (well specifically probability measures) but it means I can now be happy studying measures because I have motivation and examples.

I've now hit outer measures, at first I saw them as a way to induce a measure on a bigger space from an already existing measure, I am now questioning this.

What's the motivation for them (compared to just measures)

Before people are like "He said 'why' - vote to close ASAP!" remember how easily measures are motivated - probability. I can apply the theory directly to solving probability problems. What's the "probability theory" of outer-measures?

**Example of outer measure**

Take a 10x10 grid X and an hereditary sigma ring $\mathcal{P}(X)$

Define $\mu^*(E)$ to be the number of columns with at least one point in E.

This is an outer-measure, great! What can I do with this

This is a good example because it is not also a measure, take two disjoint sets in $H$, we only have $\mu^*(A\cup B)\le\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)$ as the A and B may overlap on columns (thus being counted once by the LHS)

So what ... what can we do with this knowledge? What is this example demonstrating?