# Limsup, is there an alternative definition or am I missing the spirit of the question?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be the positive integers
Let $H$ be $\mathcal{P}(X)$

For finite $E\in H$ $v(E)$ is the number of points in $E$.

Define:

$\mu^*(E)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{n}v(E\cap\{1,...,n\})$

My task is to prove that this is (or show that it isn't in the process) an outer measure.

**Initially** I looked at $\frac{1}{n}v(E\cap\{1,...,n\})$ as a "measure" (as in notion, not measure as in measure theory) of density. 1 being consecutive numbers starting at 1, anything less than that having a gap (for sufficiently big n)

Then I remembered what $\limsup$ actually means. It's the limit of $m\rightarrow\infty$ of a sequence $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=m}$ where $a_n=\frac{1}{n}v(E\cap\{1,...,n\})$ in this case.

As the $E$ are finite surely this limit is zero? (as we keep chopping off terms from the start)

Proof:

As the $E$ are finite, they have a largest element, this means $\exists N$ such that $v(E)=v(E\cap\{1,...,N\})$ where $N$ is that largest element. So we are looking at $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{n}v(E))=0$

This ties in with [Is this an outer measure, if so can someone explain the motivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123907/is-this-an-outer-measure-if-so-can-someone-explain-the-motivation) so anyone who sees this as measure theory (not just real analysis) please take a peek, the book (Halmos, Measure Theory) has no answers/hints in the back.

It explicitly says "for finite E" - so do I assume I am working on just an ordinary ring, and show finite subadditivity?

Answer (score 2):

$E$ does not have to be finite. Since $E \cap \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is finite for all $n$, $v(E \cap \{1,2,\ldots,n\})$ is defined for every set $E$.

An outer measure has the property that if $\displaystyle E \subset \bigcup_k F_k$, then $\mu(E) \le \displaystyle \sum_k \mu(F_k)$ (here the index $k$ is countable: finite or countably infinite).

In your example, $\mathbb N \subset \bigcup_k \{k\}$, $\mu(\mathbb N) = 1$, but $\mu(\{k\}) = 0$ for all $k$. Thus $\displaystyle \mu(\mathbb N) \not\le \sum_k \mu(\{k\})$, meaning $\mu$ is not an outer measure.

Comment: The question says "for finite E" limsup is clearly non-zero if you choose all the odd numbers for instance.

Comment: But as it isn't an outer measure I guess that doesn't matter! So the limsup being 0 bit I was right about?

Comment: You are confusing $v$ with $\mu$. The number $v(E)$ is defined for finite sets $E$. If $E$ is *any set whatsoever* then $E \cap \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is finite. Thus $\mu(E)$ is defined not just for finite sets but for every set of natural numbers.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks! I was correct about any finite set having measure 0 then? Also could you take a peek at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123907/is-this-an-outer-measure-if-so-can-someone-explain-the-motivation (I can't accept this question yet, but you'll get the tick ASAP)

Comment: That's right. If $N$ is the largest element of $E$, then $\dfrac 1n v(E \cap \{1,2,\ldots,n\}) \le \dfrac Nn$ for all $n$, and $\dfrac{N}{n} \to 0$.